# Best way to convert an Enumeration<String> to Array<String> in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Incidentally, I have an `Enumeration<String>` in Kotlin. It contains `toList()`, but I need to convert it to an `Array<String>`.

What is the best way to do this in Kotlin?

Comment: It's worth checking whether you actually need an array. In Kotlin, lists are generally preferred, as they're more flexible and better supported. Arrays are still needed for a few things such as varargs, interoperating with old code, and some low-level implementation; but for everything else, lists are usually better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lists can be converted to arrays via the `.toTypeArray` function:

```
val myEnumeration: Enumeration<String> = ...
val array = myEnumeration.toList().toTypedArray() // array is Array<String>
```

A simple extension function as a shortcut is also trivial:

```
inline fun <reified T> java.util.Enumeration<T>.toTypedArray(): Array<T> = toList().toTypedArray()
```

The reason `toTypedArray()` doesn't work directly on an Enumeration is that it needs a `Collection<T>` to be able to efficiently instantiate the new array, but going through `toList()` first is still efficient enough for most scenarios.